# Can not remove underline of a element css

Tags: css, underline, squarespace

I'm working on this site https://stagetoday.squarespace.com/ .

In the left bottom corner, there is a link, but I can't remove the text-decoration:underline when I hover over it.

I tried `text-decoration:none` and `text-decoration:none!important` but it still stays.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: please post all relevant code within the question body (we need the html to this) and your real world selector as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a border

```
#bottomBar a:hover {
  border: none;
}
```

or only this link

```
.sqs-block-content a:hover {
      border: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not an underline it's this:

```
#topbar a:hover, #container a:hover, #bottomBar a:hover {
color: #999;
border-color: #999; /* here */
-webkit-transition: border 0s ease-out;
-moz-transition: border 0s ease-out;
-o-transition: border 0s ease-out;
transition: border 0s ease-out;
}
```

Just remove the border declarations.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do :

```
border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
```

on your file site.css on line 8096 you have this. it's not an underline property but a border bottom attribute.

change this property instead.